# VS 2017 Quick Actions and Refactoring Issue

Tags: refactoring, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional v. 15.0.0-RTW.

And when press `ctrl + .` to show Quick actions and refactoring menu on any unknown type it is no longer show `using [Namespace]` like before..

Is there any solution to this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with the latest update for Visual Studio 2017 Professional (v15.2).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't update because I have no admin permission on the VS 2017 running PC.

Answer (score 0):

One reason a class will need a full namespace is if the class name is also part of a namespace. So, in your case, if you have a directory called DbCommand in your project VS will need to use the namespace when referencing the DbCommand class - it is ambiguous as to whether the identifier DbCommand is referring to the class or the namespace.